# Necklace Physics

Tags: modeling, workflow, physics

I'm trying to set up the physics to simulate a hanging necklace.

My strategy is to get:

1. A floppy string with rigid body physics
2. A rigid body pendant, with an eye hole through which to feed the string

I found [this tutorial](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=4ANT5vf5H-Y&noredirect=1) for setting up a curve to behave like the string, but it seems that curves can't be assigned rigid body physics.

What is the best approach to set up such a scene?

Comment: Create a chain of cubes using constraints, and then parent the empties to the cubes.

Comment: I can't quite figure it out.. can you explain in an answer please?

Comment: Line up a bunch of cubes, and then join the with constraints. After that, you can attach the control empties for the curve(like in the tutorial) to the cubes.