# How to make a rope in the BGE?

Tags: animation, game-engine, physics

I'm pretty sure this has been asked before, but for the life-o'-me I couldn't find it.

How would one setup the physics for rope in Blender Game Engine?

- I tried soft-body; didn't work
- Incremented/decremented the properties in different ways; didn't work
- tried writing my own; fell on it's face

So how would I make a long object move like a rope. I was planning on using it for 'dreadlocks' like the wookies from Battlefront-2 so it needs to be able to sustain being moved constantly by animations.

other uses include

- rope (dur)
- vines
- ziplines

Thanks!

Comment: I have no game engine experience.. but any chance it's related to this one? http://blender.stackexchange.com/q/15809/822

Comment: @ajwood not quite. if you switch your render setting to *blender game* you will see that the physics tab is much changed. Also no constraints work in realtime.

Comment: Does the `Hook` modifier work in BGE? Or something similar? Because you could just hook the ends of a softbody, or hook links of a chain/rope together.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The are two main ways to make a rope in the BGE. Soft bodies, and ridged body constraints.

**The ridged body constraint method.**
This is the method [Phymec](https://www.youtube.com/user/Phymec/videos) uses in videos like [this](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=oyjE5L4-1lQ). I have not gotten good results with soft bodies, so I will focus on the ridged body constraint method.
This is very easy to set up, just add a sphere, model it in to a capsule and add a *Rigid Body Joint* constraint.
[image: Rigid Body Joint constraint settings]
Then string many of the capsules in to a rope, with the next always having the target of the one before it. Set the *Pivot* to be in the middle of the two capsules (turn on *Display Pivot* to see where the pivot point is).  Also important turn on *Linked Collision*; if not on the rope will try to break apart where ever it is intersecting.
[image: rigid body rope]