# I've made a rope of extruded icospheres in BGE - how to prevent stretching?

Tags: game-engine, physics

Per the answer by David (Nice work!) to the question ["how-to-make-a-rope-in-the-bge](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/21513/how-to-make-a-rope-in-the-bge)," I've made a rope of extruded icospheres. Every physics trick I know (Which obviously aren't many) still leaves the rope stretching, as in the screenshot. What am I missing? Blender 2.79 is used.
[image: Extruded icosphere rope]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You might try to increase physics substeps. Picture:

[image]

The [documentation](https://docs.blender.org/api/blender_python_api_current/bpy.types.SceneGameData.html#bpy.types.SceneGameData.physics_step_sub) says:

> Number of simulation substep per physic timestep, higher value give better physics precision

This may potentially solve your issue.

Comment: Increased Substeps to 3, works GREAT! Thanks for your help!